# 返されるノードの優先順位について

Tags: javascript, xpath

Firefoxのウェブコンソール上で

```
<h1><span class='A'>テキスト1</span><span>テキスト2</span></h1>
```

なる形の`h1`要素に対し、

```
document.evaluate("span[@class='A']|.", <h1要素をあらわすノード>, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerText
```

と呼び出したところ、

```
"テキスト1テキスト2"
```

というテキストが得られました。これは`span[@class='A']`ではなく`.`が[文書順](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#First_Node)で先に来るノードにマッチするから（外側のノードが文書順では先だから）と考えて良いのでしょうか？

また、文書順に関わらずに`xpath1`にマッチするノードを優先し、そのようなノードが存在しない場合に`xpath2`にマッチするノードを返す、ということを単一のXPathで実現できるのでしょうか？
（上に書いた通り`xpath1 | xpath2`とするだけではダメでした。集合を返すので当然と言えば当然ですが）

Answer (score 0):

こんなところでしょうか。

```js
'use strict';
/**
 * 先にマッチしたh1要素ノード(コンテキストノード)を得る
 */
var h1 = document.evaluate("span[@class='A']|.", document.querySelector('h1'), null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(h1);  // <h1><span class='A'>テキスト1</span><span>テキスト2</span></h1>

/**
 * ルートノード(コンテキストノード)を除く要素ノードを得る
 */
var span = document.evaluate("span[@class='A']|descendant::*", document.querySelector('h1'), null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(span);  // <span class='A'>テキスト1</span>

/**
 * span[@class='A'] にマッチしなかったら、.
 */
var node = document.evaluate("span[@class='A']", document.querySelector('h1'), null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

if (!node) {
  node = document.evaluate(".", document.querySelector('h1'), null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log(node);  // <span class='A'>テキスト1</span>
```

```html
<h1><span class='A'>テキスト1</span><span>テキスト2</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

`xpath1 | xpath2[not(xpath1)]` ではどうでしょうか。

（XPath 2.0 以降で、`xpath1`, `xpath2` ともに単一ノードなら、`(xpath1, xpath2)[1]` が標準的ですが。）